# Timing out using kafka-configs.sh in Kafka 2.3

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to run below command from one of the kafka node. We have 3 Kafka broker nodes. 9092 is configured as SASL_PLAINTEXT. I keep getting below error. Can you please help fix the issue?

```
 ./bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server server1:9092,server2:9092,server3:9092 --entity-type brokers --describe --entity-name 1
Error while executing config command with args '--bootstrap-server server1:9092,server2:9092,server3:9092 --entity-type brokers --describe --entity-name 1'
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.brokerConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:346)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.describeBrokerConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:328)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.processBrokerConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:292)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.main(ConfigCommand.scala:82)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand.main(ConfigCommand.scala)
```

Adding Debug Logs:

```
[2020-05-14 09:44:21,773] DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Queueing Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1589463981670) with a timeout 119897 ms from now. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient)
[2020-05-14 09:44:21,873] DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Initiating connection to node server3:9092 (id: -3 rack: null) using address server3/30.118.176.19 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-05-14 09:44:21,874] DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 65536, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -3 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2020-05-14 09:44:21,874] DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Completed connection to node -3. Fetching API versions. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-05-14 09:44:21,874] DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Initiating API versions fetch from node -3. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-05-14 09:44:21,875] DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Recorded API versions for node -3: (Produce(0): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], Fetch(1): 0 to 11 [usable: 11], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], Metadata(3): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], StopReplica(5): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], ListGroups(16): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DeleteRecords(21): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], InitProducerId(22): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], EndTxn(26): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 [usable: 0], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeAcls(29): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], CreateAcls(30): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DeleteAcls(31): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], AlterConfigs(33): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], CreatePartitions(37): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], CreateDelegationToken(38): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], RenewDelegationToken(39): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ExpireDelegationToken(40): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeDelegationToken(41): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DeleteGroups(42): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ElectPreferredLeaders(43): 0 [usable: 0], IncrementalAlterConfigs(44): 0 [usable: 0]) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-05-14 09:44:21,976] DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection with server3/30.118.176.19 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:424)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:385)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:651)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:572)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1152)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-05-14 09:44:21,977] DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -3 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-05-14 09:44:21,977] DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1589463981670) failed: DisconnectException: Cancelled fetchMetadata request with correlation id 159 due to node -3 being disconnected. Beginning retry #2 (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient)
```

**UPDATED**

The issue with timeout is resolved when i added configuration file to make it run with SASL_PLAINTEXT. But it is not returning any result. It just says as below. So still need your valuable inputs.

```
Configs for broker 3 are:
```

Comment: Ok. I fixed this issue. Issue was that i had to pass a configuration file to make it SASL_PLAINTEXT. the query worked after that. But it didn't return any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kafka 2.3, the `kafka-configs.sh` tool only returns "dynamic configurations". These are configurations that have been changed at runtime.

From Kafka 2.5.0 onwards, the tool can also return all configurations using the `--all` flag. This is a client side change, so you can keep running the 2.3 brokers and only use 2.5.0 for the `kafka-configs.sh` tool. For reference, this change was made in [KIP-524](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-524%3A+Allow+users+to+choose+config+source+when+describing+configs).